# Pandas, iterating through a Dataframe is not writing values correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm breaking my head with this problem. I'm iterating a Dataframe thru iterrows and updating values with df.at[], but when I add an IF-ELSE statement, it seems not to work.

This is the code:

```
def join_json_Certi_2(dfK, json_info):

    dfK['json_NIF'] = ''
    dfK['json_evaluationID'] = ''

    #Para cada servicio, ejecutamos funcion. 
    for i, row in dfK.iterrows():
        print(row['dupla'])
        print(i)
        r = search_cert_json(row, json_info)
        print(r)
        
        if str(r[0]) == 'OK':
            print("Writes OK")
            dfK.at[i, "Join_PRUEBA"] = str(r[0])+': '+str(r[1])
            dfK.at[i, "json_NIF"] = str(r[2])
            dfK.at[i, "json_evaluationID"] = str(r[3])
            dfK.at[i, "json_parentServiceCode"] = str(r[3])

        if str(r[0]) == 'KO':
            print("Writes KO")
            dfK.at[i, "Join_PRUEBA"] = 'KO'

        #print ('\nDONE')

    return dfK
```

The column Join_PRUEBA ends all the values as 'KO'. When in the execution, It writes multiple times "Writes KO". So multiple times the flow goes throug the IF statement.

I'm getting all the Dataframe series "Join_PRUEBA" with 'KO' values.

Thank you all!

Comment: Hi Marcelo! Could you provide a small example dataset for the dfK and json inputs?